# Capybara + RSpec test with turbo stream passes locally but fails on Github actions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, github-actions, capybara, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulus-rails

I have a Rails7 application with Hotwire and Stimulus components. I run the tests using RSpec and Capybara with the `selenium_chrome_headless` driver. One of the actions is turbo stream. The tests are passing locally but they fail on Github actions.

From what I can see in Actions, Capybara starts Puma...

```
Capybara starting Puma
* Version 6.4.0 , codename: The Eagle of Durango
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:36901
```

... then the tests run. Unfortunately, the tests related to turbo stream action fail. There is `ActionController::UnknownFormat` in the response page content.

I tried changing the Selenium driver or explicitly specifying the JavaScript driver for the failing context.

Has anyone had a similar situation? Am I missing something regarding Github Actions?

**UPDATE**

I managed to fix it.

Before, I was using the `bin/rake` script to run the tests on Github Actions. Then I changed it to `bundle exec rspec`. Actions showed missing assets so I added `bundle exec rails assets:precompile` just before the `rspec` execution. It helped!

It seems some of the JavaScript assets were missing before.